# What's intrinsic in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I found some types in `lib.es5.d.ts`:

```js
/**
 * Obtain the return type of a constructor function type
 */
type InstanceType<T extends abstract new (...args: any) => any> = T extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;

/**
 * Convert string literal type to uppercase
 */
type Uppercase<S extends string> = intrinsic;

/**
 * Convert string literal type to lowercase
 */
type Lowercase<S extends string> = intrinsic;

/**
 * Convert first character of string literal type to uppercase
 */
type Capitalize<S extends string> = intrinsic;

/**
 * Convert first character of string literal type to lowercase
 */
type Uncapitalize<S extends string> = intrinsic;
```

There is a keyword named `intrinsic` I have never seen, even in the TS official documentation.

I thought the types like `Uppercase`, and `Lowercase` are transformed/mapped/inferred by other types like `InstanceType`. But they are not.  It seems the `intrinsic` keyword is a total black box to the user.

What's it? Should users use it in their own types?

When I try to use it:

```js
type MyCapitalize<S extends string> = intrinsic;
```

Got error:

> The 'intrinsic' keyword can only be used to declare compiler provided intrinsic types.(2795)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580

Comment: Well, as the error stated, it's a compiler thing. If you want to create your own intrinsic types you should modify the typescript compiler code.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks. The PR explains this keyword clearly.

Comment: This belongs to TS 4.1 and they are basically in the compiler which means that we cannot create our own implementation of such, hence the name :)

Comment: @WiktorZychla could you write up an answer post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The new `intrinsic` keyword is used to indicate that the type alias references a compiler provided implementation.

> It is an error to specify intrinsic anywhere but immediately following the = separator in a type alias declaration for a type named `Uppercase`, `Lowercase`, `Capitalize` or `Uncapitalize` taking a single type parameter (but, of course, it is possible that additional intrinsic implementations will be provided in the future).

[Source pointing to the Typescript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580)